# Nodejs socket.io client cannot connect to Nodejs socket.io server

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I use **NodeJS** both as the *server* and the *client*. (No web browsers)
Server seems to be working, but client does not connect. I tried to set the port in the options but it did not work. I try to connect to the port **3000** over *telnet* and it connects to something, so the server is listening.
What am I missing here?

**Server:**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')();
var port = 3000;

server.listen(port,"127.0.0.1", () => {
    console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);
});
```

**Client:**

```
const io = require('socket.io-client');

const socket = io("http://127.0.0.1:3000",{reconnect:false});

socket.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('connected to the server');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned on the [offical socket-io github page](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io#in-conjunction-with-express), you need to pass the http-server instance to the socket-io server:

```
...
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
...
```